# How to get command-line password input in Racket

Tags: racket

I am trying to get password input on the command-line without showing the password when it is typed. This code below is not suitable, because it shows the password when the user types it on the command line:

```lisp
(display "Password: ")
(define password (read-line))
```

How can I input password on the command-line using Racket?

Comment: Also see the ADDENDUM of my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a Racket question, but more of terminal's capability. Here's one solution using `stty`. There are other solutions too depending on how sophisticated you want the program to be.

```
#lang racket

(define (read-password)
  (system "stty -echo")
  (begin0 (read-line)
    (system "stty echo")
    (newline)))

(display "Password: ")
(define password (read-password))
(display "Username: ")
(define user (read-line))
(printf "User ~a's secret is: ~a\n" user password)
```

```
Password:
Username: Randall
User Randall's secret is: correcthorsebatterystaple
```

ADDENDUM: there's also a package https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/package/get-pass that provides this functionality, Install it with `raco pkg install get-pass`.